# Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'Navbar.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\NavBar.js'

Tags: reactjs

I couldn't fix the error. Idk where I do find this error from
and this is the code for App.js

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this to import your NavBar : `import NavBar from './components/NavBar'`

Answer (score 0):

In App.js file replace 3rd line with below line:

**import NavBar from './components/NavBar'**

Because you created a NavBar.js file under components folder and export it as a NavBar.

Answer (score 0):

Specify like this :

import Navbar from './components/NavBar.js'